# use django to serve downloading big zip file with some data appended

Tags: python, django, nginx, mod-wsgi

I have a views snippet like below, which get a zip filename form a request, and I want to append some string `sign` after the end of zip file

```
@require_GET
def download(request):
    ... skip
    response = HttpResponse(readFile(abs_path, sign),  content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(abs_path) + len(sign)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
    return response
```

and the `readFile` function as below:

```
def readFile(fn, sign, buf_size=1024<<5):
    f = open(fn, "rb")
    logger.debug("started reading %s" % fn)
    while True:
        c = f.read(buf_size)
        if c:
            yield c
        else:
            break
    logger.debug("finished reading %s" % fn)
    f.close()
    yield sign
```

It works fine when using `runserver` mode, but failed on big zip file when I use `uwsgi + nginx` or `apache + mod_wsgi`.

It seems timeout because need too long time to read a big file.

I don't understand why I use `yield` but the browser start to download after whole file read finished.(Because I see the browser wait until the log `finished reading %s` appeared)

Shouldn't it start to download right after the first chunk read?

Is any better way to serve a file downloading function that I need to append a dynamic string after the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django doesn't allow streaming responses by default so it buffers the entire response. If it didn't, middlewares couldn't function the way they do right now.

To get the behaviour you are looking for you need to use the [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) instead.

Usage example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-csv-files):

```
import csv

from django.utils.six.moves import range
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

class Echo(object):
    """An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
    interface.
    """
    def write(self, value):
        """Write the value by returning it, instead of storing in a buffer."""
        return value

def some_streaming_csv_view(request):
    """A view that streams a large CSV file."""
    # Generate a sequence of rows. The range is based on the maximum number of
    # rows that can be handled by a single sheet in most spreadsheet
    # applications.
    rows = (["Row {}".format(idx), str(idx)] for idx in range(65536))
    pseudo_buffer = Echo()
    writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)
    response = StreamingHttpResponse((writer.writerow(row) for row in rows),
                                     content_type="text/csv")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it  :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) instead of HttpResponse.

Comment: I just tried `StreamingHttpResponse` and it works as I expect, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use FileRespose, is a subclass of StreamingHttpResponse optimized for binary files. It uses wsgi.file_wrapper if provided by the wsgi server, otherwise it streams the file out in small chunks.

```
import os
from django.http import FileResponse
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper


def download_file(request):
    _file = '/folder/my_file.zip'
    filename = os.path.basename(_file)
    response = FileResponse(FileWrapper(file(filename, 'rb')), content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % _file
    return response
```